# Setting Canvas3D background color to transparent

Tags: qt, qml

Is there a way to set the clearcolor of a Canvas3D context to transparent?

What i want to achieve is rendering 3D Objects on top of qml items. At the moment the whole Canvas3D area is filled with its clearColor. I would like to render them with a transparent background.

I tried setting `renderer.setClearColor` and setting the context attributes, but i cant get the context to be transparent. Here is a simple example based on the standard Qt Canvas 3D Application template:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtCanvas3D 1.0
import "glcode.js" as GLCode

Item {
    width: 500
    height: 500
    Canvas3D{
        id: canvas3d
        anchors.fill: parent

        onInitializeGL: {
            var attributes = {
                alpha: true
            };
            var context = canvas3d.getContext("3d", attributes);
            GLCode.initializeGL(canvas3d);
        }

        onPaintGL: {
            GLCode.paintGL(canvas3d);
        }

        onResizeGL: {
            GLCode.resizeGL(canvas3d);
        }
    }
}
```